# Jquery syntax in .cshtml file

Tags: jquery, razor

Here is my code:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "My page";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menucontainer').hide();
});
</script>

<h2>My page</h2>

@foreach (List<MyClass> item in (List<MyClass>[])ViewData["myList"])
{
foreach (MyClass item1 in item)
{
    if (item1.name.Equals("something"))
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#idSomething').show();
            });
        </script>
        continue;
    }
}
break;
}
```

I have a breakpoint in if, in the `{`. It gets hit and then it goes to `continue;`. The code in the script: `$('#idSomething').show();` never gets hit! Why is this and how to solve this?

I also tried:

```
if (item1.name.Equals("something"))
    {
        @: ("#idSomething").show();
        continue;
    }
```

And again, the `show()` call breakpoint isn't hit.

Comment: Are you mixing server side debugging (C#) with client side debugging (javascript)?

Comment: You shouldn´t add a script tag for each item.

Comment: @Stefan Well how do I solve this?

Comment: There´s a couple of great answers to your question. Didn´t they solve your razor problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is clientside and therefore cannot be stepped through as C# code can be in the VS debugger.

To step through your javascript code there are several tools, most notably Firebug for Firefox. If you view your code in the javascript tab you can set breakpoints and step through/over/into as you would in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Razor is smart enough to handle such thing on its own, try using the `<text>` tag so it know it should dump the output without touching it:

```
@foreach (List<MyClass> item in (List<MyClass>[])ViewData["myList"])
{
    foreach (MyClass item1 in item)
    {
        if (item1.name.Equals("something"))
        {
            <text>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#idSomething').show();
                    });
                </script>
            </text>
            continue;
         }
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running in Internet Explorer, the JavaScript debugging is built into Visual Studio, but you have to set the breakpoint in the document Internet Explorer sees. When you've started the project in debug mode, you'll see a section "Script Documents" in the Solution Explorer. If you locate your JavaScript code under that section you should be able to set a breakpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up server side debugging and client-side debugging.

When you set a break point on `{` in the C# code, you are setting a breakpoint on server-side. When the page gets parsed, the breakpoint will be hit.

But at this point, the javascript is not executed. It is not even known to be javascript actually, it is just understood by the browser and will be executed when the page is rendered in the browser. To break into javascript code, you have to set a another breakpoint in the browser's javascript console.