# Razor + jQuery combining in Code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I found some examples of a combination of Razor Syntax and jQuery. For example:

[Jquery syntax in .cshtml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816413/jquery-syntax-in-cshtml-file)
[Razor View Engine and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556160/razor-view-engine-and-jquery)

What am I do trying to do? I set a Class called "MaxHeight" on the tr, but the user should only be enabled to click a Checkbox if he clicked on the + Button AND is on a Usergroup.

So my jQuery-tinkerings looks like this:

```
    function SizeButtonClicked(obj) {
        var closestTr = $(obj).closest('tr');

        if (closestTr.hasClass('maxHeight')) {
            closestTr.removeClass('maxHeight');

            @if(Roles.IsUserInRole(UserRole.Customer.ToString()) || User.IsInRole(UserRole.Admin.ToString()))
            {
                <text>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        closestTr.find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
                    </script>
                </text>
            }
         }
         else {
                closestTr.addClass('maxHeight');
                closestTr.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
```

So if the user is in the Role Customer or Admin, I'd like to remove the attr disabled and he is enabled to click the CHK.

But I guess this won't work in 1000 Years. Is it even possible to combine stuff like this? Would there be a easier solution for such Ideas?

Edith: I try to use what Warrior and Sergey said, so I made a own JS-File and pass a Parameter to check if the disabled attribute should be searched:

```
<input type="button" value="+" class="SizeButton" onclick="SizeButtonClicked(this, @(Roles.IsUserInRole(UserRole.Customer.ToString()) || User.IsInRole(UserRole.Admin.ToString())))" />
```

Does not work so far, but would something like this BE the solution for proper programming?

Comment: What do you mean "won't work in 1000 years"? What's the issue? Does the code work as written? Because there's no inherent problem with using a mix of Javascript and Razor, that's sort of the point of Razor -- to add in server-side processing for things you can't do 100% on the client side..

Comment: Is that code from a view? Can you share the complete view code?

Comment: Not really answering your question, but you're doing this the wrong way. Views need to be as straight-forward as possible. JavaScript needs to be as modular as possible. For starters look at the module pattern in JavaScript and how this resolves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

That'll actually work just fine, but you don't need the script tag in there:

```
@if(Roles.IsUserInRole(UserRole.Customer.ToString()) || User.IsInRole(UserRole.Admin.ToString()))
{
    <text>
        closestTr.find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
    </text>
}
```

It'll render like the following if you remove the script tag, and they are in the role:

```
function SizeButtonClicked(obj) {
    var closestTr = $(obj).closest('tr');

    if (closestTr.hasClass('maxHeight')) {
        closestTr.removeClass('maxHeight');

        closestTr.find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
     else {
        closestTr.addClass('maxHeight');
        closestTr.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Erik was right, in that your problem was in including a `<script>` tag where you didn't need one. It's also worth noting that the `@:` operator can eliminate the need for the `<text>` tags:

```
@if(Roles.IsUserInRole(UserRole.Customer.ToString()) || User.IsInRole(UserRole.Admin.ToString()))
{
    @:closestTr.find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

But I would echo Sergey Akopov's comment, that you really should be striving to remove javascript from your view code entirely. JQuery is particularly good at scanning your DOM elements and pulling information off of them, so if you use so-called *unobtrusive javascript* techniques you should be able to put data attributes on your elements to indicate whether this should happen, and move your javascript into its own static file.